# Create JavaScript without the option for first parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Im trying to create a plugin for jQuery that doesnt accept a starting parameter. I've been searching for different kind of tutorials but can't find it. What i want to achieve is the following:

```
$.myCode({username: 'Stackoverflow'});
```

All tutorials I found requires you to use a first parameter like:

```
$('.my-element').myCode({username: 'Stackoverflow'});
```

Anybody knows how to achieve my goal?

Comment: Just use `$.myCode = function(test) { ...`

Comment: Those are just the examples. Just write your plugin so it doesn't use the `options` argument.

Comment: First off, with the way you are trying to use your plugin method, you should be adding your `myCode` method to `jQuery.fn.myCode`.  I would highly recommend you read over the [Learn jQuery: plugins](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/) articles for more information.

Comment: If you **do not** want to force the users to use `$(selector)` first, then the way you are attaching your method to `jQuery` is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attaching the method correctly for what you are trying to achieve.  For instance:

```js
(function($){
  var options = {};
  
  $.whoIsDis = function () {
    if (typeof arguments[0] === 'string') {
      if (arguments[0] === 'iam') {
        options.username = arguments[1].username;
        console.log(`Hello ${options.username}.`);
      } else if (arguments[0] === 'whoareyou') {
        if (!options.username) {
          console.log('I...I don\'t know who I is...');
        } else {
          console.log(`I is ${options.username}!!!`);
        }
      }
    }
    
    return $;
  };
}(jQuery));

$.whoIsDis('whoareyou')
 .whoIsDis('iam', {username: 'Jimmy'})
 .whoIsDis('whoareyou');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Dummy little example, but the point here is that if you do not require already selected elements for your plugin to work, you can attach it to the `jQuery` namespace.  You only have to attach it to `jQuery.fn` if you want it to only be available if you have previously selected elements.